# How to create a superuser & random user login from a single login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am new to asp.net & C# world. Just joined as a Software Developer. I have to create a website for a forum. So i need to create one login page for three types of login mainly,1. Admin, 2.Receptionist & 3.Random User. So i need your help in this project.

Thanks
Tourniquet

Comment: Are you asking about a page for *creating* such users or where such users log into the system?

Comment: Care to expand on the question, as a third person it needs to make some sense for people around here

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to make a seperate login for an admin or any other type.
You could just use Roles for the logged in user.

I suggest you look around on asp.net authentication with roles.

This link will give you a start:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx